# A conflict exists with inherited definition flash.display:MovieClip.isPlaying in namespace public

Tags: actionscript-3, namespaces, conflict, flash-cs6

errore (private var isPlaying:Boolean;),i want paly more mp3 file for my project.help me.
Here's my code starts:

```
public class PlayerClass extends MovieClip 
{
    private var urlLoader:URLLoader;
    private const xmlPath:String = "playlist.xml";//xml path
    private var xml:XML;
    private var songs:Array;// array for song paths
    private var titles:Array;// array for song titles   
    private var currentSong:Number  = 0; 
    private var sound:Sound;
    private var context:SoundLoaderContext;
    private var channel:SoundChannel;   
    private var isPlaying:Boolean;      
    private var isStopped:Boolean;
    private var songPosition:int = 0;
}
```

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/842477 - read it

Comment: Please download the code from this link:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6WNrOzGYfx3OE4ySFZjVVRwWXc

Comment: MovieClip already has a property named [isPlaying](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#isPlaying). Call your variable something else.

Comment: Or else use `PlayerClass extends Sprite` (since sprites don't have a timeline to "play") so there is no clash with **Flash.Display.MovieClip**'s own built-in `isPlaying` status.